# JQuery Datepicker change value attribute of div when current date is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

The jQuery Datepicker is working great, but I would like the submit button to read different text based on whether or not the day selected is today. The submit button is a `<button>` and the text is the value attribute.

Is there any way to do this? My web searches haven't turned up any results.

Answer (score 0):

Try like below

```
 var dp = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
```

1) using the [above statement](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-getDate), you can get the date that has be selected in datepicker (ie., parsed as **`date`** datatype)

2) Using `date.toDateString()`, you can get the date string which can be used to compare with datepicker's date.

```
$('#datepicker').datepicker();
$('button').on('click', function () {
    var dp = $('#datepicker').datepicker("getDate");
    var today = new Date();
    if (today.toDateString() == dp.toDateString()) {
           //write your code to change the text in div
    }
});
```

**FYI:** `value` attribute is not associated with `div` element, I guess you're referring to **`custom data*`** value attribute.

If so then you can change it using [**`.data()`**](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method of jQuery.  Example

```
$('div').data('value', 'whatever you wish');
```

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zSPV5/)

Answer (score 0):

If I Understood your question correctly, **You want to make sure that date picked is today or not, upon submission of form.**

I've gone through google, ended up with an answer, Hope It work out.

```
function ValidRange(date1)
{
   var date=new date(); //Today

   //Convert these dates into milliseconds
   var date1_ms=date1.getTime();
   var date_ms=date.getTime();

   //Calculate difference between them
   var difference_ms = date_ms - date1_ms;
   return difference_ms;   // It will return 0 if date is today.
}
```

Note: You then need to parse the strings you are getting from the UI, with Date.parse, like this:

```
ValidRange(Date.parse(Date_Picked));
```

Try this.